# zio-logging behaves differently when testing scheduled tasks than on prod in ZIO

Tags: scala, zio, zio-test

I'm stuck with testing repeatable task.
Things work when run outside of test, but fail in tests. Looks like zio-logging behaves somehow differently when in test (as if it was "blocking"). When I replace logging with plaing Console calls it works, as well as when I  fork logging call.

Can anyone give me a hint what I'm doing wrong or why is this the case?

```scala
package scheduler

import zio.clock.Clock
import zio.duration.durationInt
import zio.logging.Logging
import zio.test.Assertion.equalTo
import zio.test.environment.TestEnvironment
import zio.test.{DefaultRunnableSpec, ZSpec}
import zio.{Has, Ref, ZIO}

/*
Testing ZIO-based repeated tasks. It works fine locally, but when there is logging within the task it stops working under test.
It looks like it somehow holds execution after first iteration, because adding `fork` to logging statement within `doWorkLogging` makes test pass
*/

object SimpleSpec extends DefaultRunnableSpec {

  private val doWorkLogging = for {
    _   <- ZIO.accessM[Has[Ref[Long]]](_.get.update(_ + 1))
    now <- zio.clock.instant
    _   <- zio.logging.log.info(s"Run $now")
  } yield ()

  private val doWorkConsole = for {
    _   <- ZIO.accessM[Has[Ref[Long]]](_.get.update(_ + 1))
    now <- zio.clock.instant
    _   <- zio.console.putStrLn(s"Run $now")
  } yield ()

  private val logging = Logging.console()

  override def spec: ZSpec[Environment, Any] = suite("simple test")(
    testM("logging + delay work with Clock.live") {
      val counter = Ref.make(0L).toLayer
      val looper  = doWorkLogging *> (zio.UIO.unit.delay(2.seconds) *> doWorkLogging).forever
      (for {
        f     <- looper.fork
        _     <- zio.clock.sleep(5.seconds)
        ref   <- ZIO.service[Ref[Long]]
        count <- ref.get
        _     <- f.interrupt
      } yield zio.test.assert(count)(equalTo(3L))).provideSomeLayer(Clock.live ++ logging ++ counter)
    },
    // Why is this one failing with count = 1?
    testM("logging + delay don't work with TestEnvironment") {
      val counter = Ref.make(0L).toLayer
      val looper  = doWorkLogging *> (zio.UIO.unit.delay(2.seconds) *> doWorkLogging).forever
      (for {
        f     <- looper.fork
        _     <- zio.test.environment.TestClock.adjust(5.seconds)
        ref   <- ZIO.service[Ref[Long]]
        count <- ref.get
        _     <- f.interrupt
      } yield zio.test.assert(count)(equalTo(3L))).provideSomeLayer[TestEnvironment](logging ++ counter)
    },
    // And why this one (with logging replaced with console) works then?
    testM("console + delay work with TestEnvironment") {
      val counter = Ref.make(0L).toLayer
      val looper  = doWorkConsole *> (zio.UIO.unit.delay(2.seconds) *> doWorkConsole).forever
      (for {
        f     <- looper.fork
        _     <- zio.test.environment.TestClock.adjust(5.seconds)
        ref   <- ZIO.service[Ref[Long]]
        count <- ref.get
        _     <- f.interrupt
      } yield zio.test.assert(count)(equalTo(3L))).provideSomeLayer[TestEnvironment](logging ++ counter)
    },
  )
}
```

Comment: I've tried running your test cases a few times but none of them failed. Running with `zio`,`zio-test`, `zio-test-sbt` @ 1.0.5 and `zio-logging` @ 0.5.8. What was your failure message?

Comment: I just saw in the comments that you `count` was stuck at 1. I can verify on my side that all counters are counting fine when I increase the adjusted time.

Comment: These are exactly the versions I have...

Comment: Have you tried running them one by one?

Comment: Yep, one by one as well as all together.

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/3ctGBfwxQS6Owx8Rutk3vQ

Comment: Whoa, looks like the issue sits somewhere in the ZIO test runner for IntelliJ, because when run from `sbt test` or via regular IntelliJ app runner they all pass. Thanks for help!